# Python: how do you loop from 'A' through 'Z', and then finish off with '_'?

Tags: python

Within the loop, there's tons of code, so I don't want to just duplicate all of that code again just to be able to incorporate the '_' case.

So it would go through A, B, C, .. Y, Z, _

without any code duplication

Answer (score 4):

Construct a string containing those characters and tack on a `_`, then loop through it:

```
import string

for char in string.ascii_uppercase + '_':
    # ...
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [`string.ascii_uppercase`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.ascii_uppercase) and simply concatenate the `_`:

```
from string import ascii_uppercase

for c in ascii_uppercase + '_':
```

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate through each character of a string:

```
for c in 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_':
    # tons of code
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use [`itertools.chain()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) (along with [`string.ascii_uppercase`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.ascii_uppercase) as has been suggested by other answers):

```
from itertools import chain
from string import ascii_uppercase

for c in chain(ascii_uppercase, '_'):
    ...
```